# Setting compiler right for meson

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, meson-build

I am trying to build a basic Qt Application with the Meson Build System on my Mac (using macOS Sierra), following the tutorial on http://mesonbuild.com/samples.html.

My meson.build file looks like this:

```
project('qt5 demo', 'cpp',
    default_options : ['cpp_std=c++11'])

qt5_dep = dependency('qt5', modules : ['Core', 'Gui', 'Widgets'])

# Import the extension module that knows how
# to invoke Qt tools.
qt5 = import('qt5')
prep = qt5.preprocess(moc_headers : 'mainWindow.h',
                  ui_files : 'mainWindow.ui')

executable('qt5app',
  sources : ['main.cpp', 'mainWindow.cpp', prep],
  dependencies : qt5_dep,
  cpp_args : '-std=c++11')
```

I have a small test program consisting of only four files: main.cpp, mainwindow.h, mainwindow.cpp, and mainwindow.ui.

The source code is as follows.

main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainWindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

The program compiles and executes as expected when I use qmake as a build system using the following qmake-file:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = QtDesigner
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

When I execute

```
meson build
```

it works fine, except for the warning:

```
WARNING: rcc dependencies will not work reliably until this upstream issue is fixed: 
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-45460
```

It also compiles without errors, when I switch to the build directory and call

```
ninja
```

but when I execute the program I get the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore
  Referenced from: 
/Users/<myname>/code/C++/QtDesignerCode/build/./qt5app
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

It seems like the linker cannot find the libraries? Which is weird, as in Qt Creator (using qmake) the source code compiles fine.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following in the `build` dir

```
mesonconf -Dcpp_std=c++11
```

or, set [the default language version](http://mesonbuild.com/howtox.html#set-default-cc-language-version) in your `meson.build` file

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not solve the issue. I still get the following error:

  Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  ...
  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see 
  invocation)
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

I think it is not the C++11 but something with the linker which I don't get right.

Comment: Ok, I found I forgot to include the Qt modules 'Gui' and 'Core' in the meson.build. Now it compiles and links fine, but now I get the following error, when starting the application:

`dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore
  Referenced from: /Users/<myname>/sciebo/code/C++/QtDesignerCode/build/./qt5app
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
`

Comment: You'd better edit your question and include minimum source code to reproduce the error you are seeing.  Because, I can't reproduce it.  All I did was to generate simple `mainwindow.cpp` and other files from qt creator, and put the `meson.build` from the URL you mentioned in the same dir.  It just works fine here.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I edited the question and provided the sample code.